# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word reference is missing and no solution is found

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, com, office-interop

I have a project that uses Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word reference. This reference is broken so I have to re-reference it. For some strange reason the COM tab does not contain it. I tried to add Microsoft Object reference but it's different - it gives me only Microsoft.Office.Core assembly and not Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.
I googled and stackoverflowed and I found suggestions to install some PIARedistr.exe from msdn site. For some strange reason when I run this unzipped app it says something like "gather information" and then the window disappears so it's not clear what's going on but anyway it does not effect on the COM tab: I still don't see the assembly I need.
What should I do?

Comment: Do you have Word installed on the machine?

Answer (score 2):

You can use NuGet Package Manager to add it to your project for you

1. In Visual Studio (2015) with your solution open go to **Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...**
2. Go to the **Browse** tab
3. Type in **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word**
4. Click on "**Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word by Microsoft**" in the search results then **tick the project**(s) that you want to add the reference to
5. Click [**Install**] button

Answer (score 0):

In *COM* tab, try with **Microsoft Word XX.X Object Library**.

XX.X is the version: 14.0, 15.0 and so.

This should adds references to *Microsoft.Office.Core* and *Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word*

Comment: this is not an answer.. and `Works for me is just as bad as saying "It works on my machine"`

Comment: It does not work. I mentioned in my post that it adds only .Core reference and not Interop.Word

Answer (score 0):

To see the reference on the COM tab of the Add Reference dialog you need to install Word with .net programmability support option selected in the installation wizard. See [How to: Install Office Primary Interop Assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/kh3965hw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.

The PIA redistributable package installs PIAs into the GAC. They will not be visible on the COM tab in VS. Did you have a chance to look at GAC assemblies?